# Views aggregation compress using multiple fields combination

Tags: views

Good day,
I saw Views Agreggation allows to group+compress una field only.
I need to have a grouping action of a combination of fields, this is how I can figure it out:

**TABLE:**

```
product | color | origin  | value
----------------------------------
p0001   | green | america | 150.00
p0002   | green | america | 180.00
p0003   | red   | africa  | 180.00
p0004   | red   | asia    | 180.00
p0005   | red   | america| 180.00
```

I need this **GROUPED RESULT:**

```
product     | color | origin  | value
----------------------------------
p0001,p0002 | green | america | 330.00
p0003       | red   | africa  | 180.00
p0004       | red   | asia    | 180.00
p0005       | red   | america | 180.00
```

Both, color and origin are my keys to group, and the value is a sum, product is grouped comma separated.

I do not know if it was clearly explained. Thanks